# How to load css & js from public folder reactjs create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

i created create-react-app and i placed index.html and css in public folder and imported css and js using link and script tags but not working completely, could any one please help me on this.

Comment: You'd keep your source code inside `src` folder, code from `public`isn't processed by webpack.

Comment: You should be importing the CSS & JS in your components. They will automatically be handled by webpack when it runs.

Comment: did npm run eject but still same problem and even imported css in app.js its showing outside src not allowed.